# artifitially call javascript event

Tags: javascript

I have a function:

```
function something(event){

var a = event.getSource();
var b = a.getParent();

//do some stuff

}
```

I am inserting this javascript inside a J2EE framework page, and due to the limitations of the framework I must call this function artificially. The event will always come from the same source (button). Is it possible to call this function as if the button was clicked without actually clicking the button or programmatically using a click event? I need some type of hardcode way. I tried removing the event parameter and hard-coding the string which is shown by **event.getSource()** but this did not work.

Comment: you first need to identify the scope in which your function exists - is it in the global scope, in a closure, exposed on an object, etc...?

Comment: it is in global scope

Comment: everything defined in the global scope is a property of the `window` object, you can call it through `window.myFunction()`

Comment: but I need to get the source of the event, how would I do this?